# Lightslider bugging out inside featherlight on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/2patspw2/3429/

I am using featherlight as my modal box and am running lightslider inside of it. It runs fine the first time it is clicked, but them for some reason it seems to bug out and duplicate itself. I had thought it might be duplicate slides so I read light slider documentation and added this:

```
 onSliderLoad: function(el) {
        el.lightGallery({
          selector: '.gal .lslide'
        });
```

This didn't fix the problem, so then I tried doing an each() of function (index) like so:

```
$('.inline').each(function(index) {
  $(document).on("click", '.modal', function() {
// relevant code
});
});
```

I bound it to a delegated event since I have to activate via an on:click. However the element still seems to duplicate itself?

HTML:

```
<a href=".inline" class="modal" data-featherlight>Inline</a>

<div class="inline">
  <ul class="gal">
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-1.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-1.jpg"> TEST!!!!
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-2.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-2.jpg"> YEAH!!!
  </ul>
</div>

<a href=".inline-two" class="modal" data-featherlight>Inline2</a>

<div class="inline-two">
  <ul class="gal">
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-1.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-1.jpg"> asfasdf
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-2.jpg">
      <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-2.jpg"> YEAH!!!
  </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).each(function(index) {
  $('.modal').on("click", function() {
    $('.gal').lightSlider({
      gallery: true,
      item: 1,
      loop: true,
      thumbItem: 9,
      slideMargin: 0,
      enableDrag: false,
      currentPagerPosition: 'left',
      onSliderLoad: function(el) {
        el.lightGallery({
          selector: '.gal .lslide'
        });
      }
    });
  })
});
```

Why is the carousel essentially duplicate the navigation and bugging out?
*Note* I tried doing `loop: false` as well, and it didn't change anything.